# How can I pass parameters to @Provide?

Tags: java, jqwik

Is there a way to pass parameters to `@Provide`? I want something equivalent to the following:

```
@Property
void test(@ForAll("charSequence", 2, 5) CharSequence cs) {
    // test property on cs, which is an arbitrary CharSequence of length minimum 2 and maximum length 5
}

@Provide
Arbitrary<CharSequence> charSequence(int minLength, int maxLength) {
    Arbitrary<String> stringArbitrary = Arbitraries.strings().ofMinLength(minLength).ofMaxLength(maxLength).injectNull(0.01);
    Arbitrary<StringBuffer> stringBufferArbitrary = stringArbitrary.map
        (str -> null == str ? null : new StringBuffer(str));
    Arbitrary<StringBuilder> stringBuilderArbitrary = stringArbitrary.map
        (str -> null == str ? null : new StringBuilder(str));
    return Arbitraries.oneOf(stringArbitrary, stringBufferArbitrary, stringBuilderArbitrary);
}
```

I tried creating a custom annotation

```
public @interface Length {
    int min();
    int max();
}
```

and using it as `void test(@ForAll("charSequence") @Length(min = 2, max = 5) CharSequence cs)` as suggested in [Provider Methods with Parameters](https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html#provider-methods-with-parameters), but `TypeUsage` doesn't seem to pick up the custom annotation, `@Length`. (Only `@ForAll` is picked.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no mechanism in jqwik to directly pass parameters to provider methods. The annotation mechanism, however, should work as you suggested:

```
@Property
void test(@ForAll("charSequence") @Length(min = 2, max = 5)  CharSequence cs) {
    System.out.println(cs);
}

@Provide
Arbitrary<CharSequence> charSequence(TypeUsage typeUsage) {
    Optional<Length> optionalLength = typeUsage.findAnnotation(Length.class);
    int minLength = optionalLength.map(l -> l.min()).orElse(1);
    int maxLength = optionalLength.map(l -> l.max()).orElse(255);

    Arbitrary<String> stringArbitrary = Arbitraries.strings().ofMinLength(minLength).ofMaxLength(maxLength);
    Arbitrary<StringBuffer> stringBufferArbitrary =
        stringArbitrary.map(str -> null == str ? null : new StringBuffer(str));
    Arbitrary<StringBuilder> stringBuilderArbitrary =
        stringArbitrary.map(str -> null == str ? null : new StringBuilder(str));

    return Arbitraries.oneOf(
            stringArbitrary, 
            stringBufferArbitrary, 
            stringBuilderArbitrary
    );
}
```

I guess you forgot to switch on runtime retention for `@Length`, otherwise the annotation will just be removed by the compiler:

```
@Target({ ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Length {
    int min();
    int max();
}
```

The above code should generate output similar to (sequences of length between 2 and 5):

```
ꭀ訂
쯈쓁緈ﵬ
堰⾞ᒽ뒡ՙ
ᒽ뒡
쳨任๔蔢
涼嵒퓗
⫈ࣦ᩿쯧佺
佺㺻
䲠燷怟藤
...
```

Comment: Thanks! `@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)` should be sufficient, right? Also, is there a way to use the provider if it's in a separate file?

Comment: `@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)` suffices for your use case.
As for reusing providers across container classes: that's what domains are for: https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html#domain-and-domain-context